# How to calculate total number of comments made by a particular user

Tags: plugins

When I use the following custom query

```
$wp_comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_comments WHERE userid=$userid")
```

If I use

```
print_r(wp_comments)
```

I get the following printed

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 10 ) )
```

10 is the count I am expecting, how to print out the value?

Is there any other way to get the number of comments made by the user on the whole site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `get_comments` function to retrive the comment count.Pass the user id of perticuler user as an argument.

```
$args = array(
    'user_id' => 1, // use user id
    'count' => true //return only the count
    );
$comments = get_comments($args);
echo $comments
```

Please refer below link for more information.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

Comment: That Worked. But i have a custom db table wp_ratings created by wp_postratings plugin, I need to get total number of ratings made by the logged in user. the table have "rating_userid" column that logs the userid. how to do that?

Comment: @JaganK '$wp_comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as comment_count FROM wp_comments WHERE userid=$userid")' echo $wp_comments[0]->comment_count; use this code.